# Package download is fast but takes 5 minutes to begin

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, internet, synaptic

I download packages all the time, through Synaptic and by apt-get commands. When I'm at school, the downloads are fast and start without any delay. However, when I'm at home and do the same thing, it takes a while to connect to 'security.ubuntu.com' and begin. The download is about the same speed either location, but at home the connection is extremely delayed. Any idea as to why this is happening? It is bearable but just gets a little irritating. Also, apt-adding a repository (e.g. ppa:repositoryname) is just as fast as at school even if I'm at home... Final thing to note: the speeds are the same when using apt-get in the terminal as using Synaptic (or occasionally the Software Centre).

Comment: Maybe network restrictions.

Comment: This hints to problems with domain name resolution. Check if the nameservers from /etc/resolve.conf can be pinged and respond to `host` requests.

Comment: thanks phillip i'll look into it... once my computer boots XD

Comment: I've forgotten about this post but I'd like to thank you again now that I've come back across it. It did work, it turned out that I had changed the hostname in System Settings > Details, but /etc/resolve.conf didn't update to match.